# react native: StyleSheet.compose(a, b) is deprecated; use array syntax, i.e., [a,b] error when using google signin

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, google-signin

when integrating google sign-in in my react native app, i get the following error:
[image]

I was testing earlier and it was fine, but after adding some functionalities i got this error. Now, i tried to comment the new things i added, and even then, it's not working, any idea on how to fix it?

I am trying to integrate the google-signin api.

PS: i am not using the window.close nor the stylesheet.compose functions in my code.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to SO. In the rules it is discouraged to link to screenshots, it is recommended that you copy and paste the errors into the editor and show them as code. This helps potential solvers copy that and search for answers.

Comment: did you just try to just follow the suggestion given by the error message by using the array syntax instead passing 2 individual arguments?